# Embed external images for use in HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I'm using JavaScript to load an image into my Canvas element in Firefox. This works fine for local images, but throws a security exception for external images. Is there any way to avoid this security exception, one that does not involve my server having to act as proxy to load the image locally (because that would stress my server)?

PS: The current code is similar to this:

```
var img = new Image();
var contextSource = canvasSource.getContext('2d');
contextSource.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
// get image data to do stuff with pixels
var imageDataSource = contextSource.getImageData(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it might be as well possible by utilizing XHR level 2 and UrlData. Check out [my blog post](http://www.roomd.net/cleaning-remote-images-from-taint-to-use-with).

Comment: Indeed you show that is really possible to get images from other domains.

Comment: As neat as it is, Stanislav's method depends on cross-origin resource sharing.  If you can rig the CORS access-control-allow-origin to allow your domain, you own the domain and it might as well not be an "external" server.

Comment: Can be the same server with a different domain/subdomain. Honestly i was looking for a way to bring images from a CDN for html5 games/apps.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable for images under 25.6k in size.  Use YQL's data:uri converter to grab the image and hand you back the base-64 encoded block.  Then create an image in the client and set its source to the data you received from YQL.  Example here:

http://kentbrewster.com/avatar-portraits

Here's a link to the right [YQL data table](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20data.uri%20where%20url=%22http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/pps/yql32.png%22).

[edited to fix; it's 25.6k, not 256]

Comment: Are you sure that isn't less than 25K, not 256K?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, because this could open the browser to cross domain attacks.

Comment: Oh oops. I thought that you answered after i did. Should look better at the year